# C#: How to get the name (with prefix) from XElement as string?

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xelement, prefix

This might be duplicate since my question seems so trivial, but I haven't been able to find the answer here on [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com).

I have an *XElement* with data like this:

```
<abc:MyElement>My value</abc:MyElement>
```

**Question:**
How do I get the complete name with prefix as a string from the XElement?

**Expected result**:

```
abc:MyElement
```

Answer (score 10):

My solution so far has been to use the method `GetPrefixOfNamespace` available in the `XElement`.

Though not a pretty solution, it gives me what I want:

```
XElement xml = new XElement(...);
string nameWithPrefix = xml.GetPrefixOfNamespace(xml.Name.Namespace) + 
                        ":" + 
                        xml.Name.LocalName;
```

More elegant solutions are very welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Correct I was not using the same objects as you. with LINQ namesapce you the solution is:

```
using System.Xml.XPath; // <-- Add this namespace.

XNamespace ci = "http://foo.com";
XElement root = new XElement(ci + "Root", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "abc", "http://foo.com"));
XElement childElement = new XElement(ci + "MyElement", "content");
root.Add(childElement);
var str = childElement.XPathEvaluate("name()"); // <-- Tell Xpath to do the work for you :).
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

prints

```
abc:MyElement
```

Comment: That looks good, if I was using an `XmlElement`. But since I am using an `XElement` it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Does `string.Format("{0}:{1}", XElement.Prefix, XElement.Name)` not work?

Comment: I don't have any property `Prefix` on the `XElement`. It would be a very nice solution if I had though :)

Comment: Which version of the framework are you using? [MSDN](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.xml.linq.xelement.aspx&ei=UVz_TZrfIKTViAKB5oiOBQ&usg=AFQjCNEv3mDy6Q_VL7I6P_fn3f4CEnAqhg&sig2=O1rNLKqaMVCmNxFJyYlu4g) shows it having that property.

Comment: Can you direct me closer? I cannot find the property/method `Prefix`. I can find the method `public string GetPrefixOfNamespace(XNamespace ns)` and so far I have used that one to give me the prefix.

Comment: You are right.  I don't know why I thought it was there... your solution looks like the best one to me, unless you wanted to do some XPath style LINQ queries, but that is definitely not more elegant.

Comment: Well your suggestion was still just what I wished for ;)

Comment: This comment could potentially have been the answer, and you can't mark a comment as an answer.  If this suggestion were to have fixed the questioner's problem, I would like to have been marked as the answer...

Comment: No that would not work when running through XDocument stuff, such as Save.

Answer (score 0):

```
XNamespace ci = "http://foo.com";
XElement myElement = new XElement(ci + "MyElement", "MyValue");
XElement rootElement = new XElement("root",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "abc", ci), myElement);

var str = myElement.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

prints

```
<abc:MyElement xmlns:abc="http://foo.com">MyValue</abc:MyElement>
```

Comment: I have tried to make my question more clear. I just want the prefix and the element name (`abc:MyElement`) - not the entire element with namespaces and value.

Answer (score -1):

This will return prefix from XElement:

```
myElement.GetPrefixOfNamespace(node.Name.Namespace);
```

Comment: No it does not, it returns the URI part of the namespace, not the prefix.